# Segue Unwind isn't firing

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboard, unwind-segue

Environment: 
iOS 8.2 
Xcode 6.2

Scenario: 
A Container ViewController containing child view controllers via customized segues off of an embedded segue.

Here's the relationship:
[image]

I can pop from the table view (origin) into the 'Media Collection' view controller (destination) via a customized segue.  However I can't return (back to origin) using the unwind segue:

[image]

...even though I see the IBAction from the unwind menu:

[image]

But the action method is still not linked to the Unwind icon.
As you can see, there's no indication of a link:
[image]

How can I get this link and have it function?

How can I get

```
println("--- {EditContainer} returned ---")
```

to work?

---

Revision: 
I manually linked the container's 'back' button to the origin's unwind handler per feedback suggestion:

[image]

[image]

Here's the origin's unwind handler (abridged):
[image]

However, once again, I don't get a link. 
**Note:** This is from the container which has the 'back' button and not from the destination; with an intend link to the origin member within the container. *- that fails.*

Comment: Upvoting because of the quality of the post. Thank you.

Comment: have the same issue.. you get a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

returnToEditList(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) needs to be in the origin view controller for the unwind to be called. If it is in the Media Collection controller it will never fire.

Comment: The 'returnToEditList' call back was in the CONTAINER, not the 'Media Collection controller'.   I tried to link from the button to the origin (member 'EditList' controller) instead per your suggestion.  But apparently, this doesn't have any effect.  See modified query above.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixed up. The unwind method has to be in the view controller you are going back to. Add a prepareForSegue in your controller that your are segueing from. See if that gets fired.

Comment: It may be best to not use the unwind and link to an IBAction that does a dismissViewControllerAnimated(_:completion:)

Comment: 1) I tried to link the button (in containerVC) to the exitVC icon of the origin VC.  That didn't have any effect.  2) Then I placed the 'prepareForSegue in in the origin as well; again no effect.  3) The action does fire and I tried that; but again no effect when attempting to 'dismissViewController...'.   So I"m studying a sample segue paradigm that Apple has available that uses a UINavigationBar to keep track of the <historic> UIViewControllers that the segue can access.  There  must be a way to do this...shall pursue.

Comment: I decided to do the hybrid approach: use IBAction to access the Custom Segue to/from container which replaces the current child UIViewController of the container (original destination) with the intended child destination (original origin) UIViewController.